# Run JAX-WS client on Jboss 7.1.3

Tags: jax-ws, jboss7.x

I am trying to consume web service in web app on jboss.
Web service WSDL: https://uk.ws.ondemand.qas.com/ProOnDemand/V3/ProOnDemandService.asmx?WSDL

Firstly I created stand alone runnable class:
I created stub methods using wsimport and then use dummy code to perform simple query:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try {
        QASOnDemandIntermediary service = new QASOnDemandIntermediary();

        QAQueryHeader qaQueryHeader = new QAQueryHeader();
        QAAuthentication authenticationInfo = new QAAuthentication();
        authenticationInfo.setUsername(USERNAME);
        authenticationInfo.setPassword(PASSWORD);

        qaQueryHeader.setQAAuthentication(authenticationInfo);

        QAPortType port = service.getQAPortType();
        QACanSearch body = new QACanSearch();
        body.setCountry("GBR");
        EngineType engineType = new EngineType();
        engineType.setValue(EngineEnumType.SINGLELINE);
        body.setEngine(engineType);
        QASearchOk result = port.doCanSearch(body, qaQueryHeader, new Holder<QAInformation>());

        System.out.println("Webservice call result: " + result.isIsOk());

    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine = it is quick, is getting through and returns correct response.

After this test I copied code to servlet method. 
Build and deploy war and call servlet method (from browser)
Unfortunately it fails to connect to web service with errors:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
...
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.doCanSearch(Unknown Source)
...
java.net.ConnectException: ConnectException invoking https://ws.ondemand.qas.com/ProOnDemand/V3/ProOnDemandService.asmx: Connection refused: connect
    sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1453)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1438)
...
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
```

JDK:7u45

Jboss:7.1.3-redhat4

Service Certificate is signed by trust CA installed on my machine

I can download WSDL from Jboss using apache httpclient (so it is not firewall issue)

Could you help me get it working?

Answer (score 0):

May be your proxy is restricting connection.
You can bypass proxy by adding below code.

```
//proxy setting
System.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("proxyHost", "proxy_ip");
System.setProperty("proxyPort", "proxy_port");
```